# Multiple pspicture environments breaks when using \pstMarkAngle

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pst-eucl

I have a pretty weird problem. If I use multiple `pspicture` environments in the same document, the first one gets rendered, but the other breaks. For example,

```
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode[PointName=none](0, 0){O}
    \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=N](1, 0.66){N}  
    \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=B](-1, 1){B}
    \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=W](0, -2){W}

    \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{N}
    \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{B}
    \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{W}

    \pstMarkAngle[linecolor=black, Mark=none]{N}{O}{B}{}
\end{pspicture}
```

followed by something ala'

```
\begin{pspicture}(3,5)
    \pstTriangle[PointSymbol=none, linecolor=black, linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth](0,4){A}(0,0){B}(3,0){C}
\end{pspicture}
```

makes the second element break, however, if i have just two of the second element there is no problem. Taking out the `\pstMarkAngle` line of the first enviroment seems to fix the problem.

So, my question in all its simplicity, how do I use `pstMarkAngle` without breaking subsequent `pspicture` environments?

EDIT: complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
        \item
        \begin{center}
        \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
            \pstGeonode[PointName=none](0, 0){O}
            \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=N](1, 0.66){N}  
            \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=B](-1, 1){B}
            \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=W](0, -2){W}
            \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{N}
            \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{B}
            \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{W}
            \pstMarkAngle[Mark=none]{N}{O}{B}{}
        \end{pspicture}
        \end{center}
     \item
        \begin{center}
        \begin{pspicture}(3,5)
            \pstTriangle[PointSymbol=none, linecolor=black, linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth]
            (0,4){A}(0,0){B}(3,0){C}
        \end{pspicture}
        \end{center}    
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

gives the following error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

** WARNING ** Filtering file via command -->rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='/var/folders/ry/zcbxz44d46j7w58g2cvh8vf40000gp/T//dvipdfmx.NEz14AXD' '/var/folders/ry/zcbxz44d46j7w58g2cvh8vf40000gp/T//dvipdfmx.EXaHSm0G' -c quit<-- failed.
** WARNING ** Image format conversion for PSTricks failed.
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command pst: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(275.731, 343.294)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "pst:  tx@Dict begin STP newpath /ArrowA { moveto } def /ArrowB "
** WARNING ** 7 memory objects still allocated
You may want to report this to tex-k@tug.org
```

and the second `pspicture` does not get rendered. Removing the `\pstMarkAngle` element resolves the problem.

**UPDATE**:
using latex instead of XeLaTeX works. I suppose my installation of XeLaTeX (which came with TeXLive 2012) is buggy.

Comment: I cannot see any problem with current TL 2012. Create a _complete_ example which shows your problem.

Comment: I tried adding the full document.

Comment: @JustDanyul: A *complete* document starts with `\documentclass` and ends in `\end{document}`. Remove whatever is unnecessary while still being able to re-produce the problem. See how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: You need to let us know what packages you're using.  If I load `article` class and the packages `enumitem` and `pst-eucl`, I get a working document with everything marked up as expected.

Comment: @JustDanyul: No, I also have xelatex from TL 2012 and it works well. The problem is your missing _complete_ example then we can say what's going wrong. With a `\listfiles` one can compare versions between different machines

Comment: @Herbert but, isn't it peculiar that the document A.Ellet provided doesn't compile here either? I've updated the question to contain a complete example

Comment: @herbert.  I'm actually having problems with my example using `xelatex`.  I can get everything to work through `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` without a hitch.  But `xelatex` does indeed seem to have a problem with `pstMarkAngle`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a document that works as expected and produces no error messages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
        \item First diagram
        \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{pspicture}[shift=-3,showgrid=true](-3,-3)(3,3)
            \pstGeonode[PointName=none](0, 0){O}
            \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=N](1, 0.66){N}  
            \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=B](-1, 1){B}
            \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=W](0, -2){W}
            \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{N}
            \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{B}
            \pstLineAB[linecolor=black]{O}{W}
            \pstMarkAngle[Mark=none]{N}{O}{B}{}
        \end{pspicture}
        \hspace*{\fill}
     \item Second diagram
        \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{pspicture}[shift=-2,showgrid=true](3,5)
            \pstTriangle[PointSymbol=none, linecolor=black, linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth]
            (0,4){A}(0,0){B}(3,0){C}
        \end{pspicture} 
        \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I've changed a couple of things.

1. I got rid of the centering.  That creates extra vertical space that you probably really don't want or need.  `pstricks` comes with a `shift=<num>` key that will allow you to reset the baseline for the `pspicture`.
2. If you want to center the picture on the page, I'd just use `\hspace*{\fill}` on either side.  Though technically, this is centered within the current `\linewidth` which has been shifted to the right by the indentation of created by the enumeration environments.
3. I prefer the package `enumitem` to whatever you were using.  The keys are more explicit and meaningful.
4. I've also used `showgrid=true` to help illustrate the positioning of everything in the picture.

Here's what this looks like:

[image]

Comment: thank you for taking the time, unfortunately, this gives the same error as my initial version on my machine. I suspect the problem is with XELATEX